# Getting python to answer "The total net amount of "Profit/Losses" over the entire period"

Tags: python

I'm trying to get python to sum a column from a csv file that I imported.  The column includes both positive and negative numbers.  Every time I run my script, the output I get is 0 (zero).  I'm a noob at python so if you could point me in a direction, I would appreciate it.  I'm guessing I'm asking my code to calculate the wrong cells, but the numerous variations I've tried have all resulted in the same output.
[image]

Comment: please do not post code as images, makes users unable to copy (especially with this big code), please post code as code, to do it just paste the code in stackoverflow, then highlight it then hit Ctrl-K, or after highlighting, hit `{}` menu

Comment: Posting your code as an image makes it much harder for people to help you.

Comment: What do you see if you write `print(row[1])` before `int(row[1])`

Comment: Once you have read all rows from `csvreader` it is exhausted and does not yield lines anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your `csvreader` iterator is already exhausted when you do:

```
row_count = sum(1 for row in csvreader)
```

so when you try to iterate over it again in:

```
for row in csvreader:
```

there's nothing to iterate over as the file pointer already reaches the end of file.

You should reset the file pointer the `csvreader` is associated with so that you can iterate over it again.

Add the following after `row_count = sum(1 for row in csvreader)`:

```
csvfile.seek(0)
next(csvreader)
```

and your code would work.

But then again, there's no need to iterate over `csvreader` twice to begin with because all the first iteration does is to get the number of rows, which can easily be done in the second iteration by initializing `row_count` before the loop and incrementing `row_count` for each iteration.